# Can network share that needs path move to Sharepoint?

Tags: migration, file-shares

We have couple network shares that their content is connected to some software so that mean that the path is needed. The path cant be changed otherwise software wont be able to locate the files.

But what we would like to do is that move these shares into SharePoint.

IS this possible? I have been looking at google but i couldnt find any articles about it so i am quite stuck

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have network drive (shared drive) where files are stored, this shared drive path is connected and control by some other third party tool, and now you want to move these files into SharePoint.

So, as far as shared drive migration is concerned in SharePoint, it won't create any issues. Because you need to create two connection 1. one source data connection i.e file share path, here no matter what software or third party tool is being used in that and 2.Target data connection i. e your target SharePoint site connection.

For this migration you can use any third-party data migration tool like sharegate, Metalogix etc or even Microsoft data migration tool (free version available).

License cost wise sharegate is much cheaper than the Metalogix, however both have trials version.